# Matching data across two data frames in R

Tags: r, search, match

I've found a number of answers to my question that almost get me to the result I want, but not quite!

I've got two data sets that include word lists, something like:

```
df1:                          
Word  |  Speaker 
apple     1
dog       1
lobster   1
tree      2

df2:
Word  |  Speaker
car       2
lobster   2
fish      1
bird      1
```

I want to create a new column in df1 that will tell me whether or not the same word appears in df2, regardless of exactly where in the list it occurs and who the speaker was. So I want to create a new column in df1, similar to this:

```
df1
Word  |  Speaker | Match
apple     1        FALSE
dog       1        FALSE
lobster   1        TRUE
tree      2        FALSE
```

It seems that it should be very easy but I can't quite get it to do the right thing. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're right - it is easy!  You need `%in%`...

```
df1$Match <- (df1$Word %in% df2$Word)
```